# QGIS Topology Checker select errors

Tags: qgis, topology

I have used the Topology Checker plugin in QGIS to create rules to identify errors in my layer. For example, I have used it to search for all overlapping polygons. This plugin is great for finding such errors, but how can I select them in my original layer. I have a very large data set and doing them by hand is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible. Your best bet is to probably use the `v.clean` tool from GRASS to automate the fixing of errors. There's a number of cleaning functions available within the `v.clean` tool such as:

- Break: Breaks lines at each intersection
- snap: Snaps lines to vertex in threshold
- rmdangle: Removes dangles
- rmline: Removes all lines or boundaries of zero length, threshold is ignored
- rmsa: Removes small angles between lines at nodes